# Using the fact that $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ to prove that the unit sphere is compact in $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the unit sphere
$$S=\{x\in X \:\:|\: ||x||=1\}$$
is compact in any normed vector space $X$.

If $X$ was $\mathbb{R}^n$, then I could use Heine-Borel and the result would be trivial. Can't I use the fact that $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? If so, how?

I can't use equivalence of norms to prove this since I am using this theorem to prove the equivalence of norms but I can use $||x||=||x||_1$.

PS: There are several posts here trying to prove this result but none using the isomorphism of $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and explaining this step convincingly.

Comment: All finite dimensional normed vector spaces are complete so it should be sufficient to show that $S$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: $X$ *has* to be finite dimensional, or else the result is false.

Comment: It's a theorem of Riesz that the unit ball (whence sphere) is compact iff you are in finite dimensions.

Comment: "I can't use equivalence of norms to prove this since I am using this theorem to prove the equivalence of norms but I can use $||x||=||x||_1$."? Proving that any two norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent (in the sense that they induce the same topology) doesn't require any reasoning about compactness. If you can "use" $||x||=||x||_1$ (i.e., if you can assume the norm in question is the 1-norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$), then your question becomes trivial.

Comment: Rob Arthan, see this https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a finite-dimensional normed linear space $X$ over $\mathbb R$ with basis $b_1, \ldots, b_n$, the map 
$f: (c_1, \ldots, c_n) \to c_1 b_1 + \ldots + c_n b_n $ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $X$ is continuous (by continuity of scalar multiplication and addition in $X$), one-to-one and onto (by definition of basis).  The closed unit ball $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact, so $f(B)$ is compact.  So is $f(rB) = r f(B)$ for any $r > 0$, where $rB = \{r x: x \in B\}$.

Since 
$x \mapsto \|f(x)\|$ is a continuous real-valued function on the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^n$ (which is a compact set), it attains a minimum value $L$ there, and $L > 0$ because $f$ is one-to-one.  Thus $\|f(x)\| \ge L > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\| = 1$, and by homogeneity $\|f(x)\| \ge L \|x\|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.  In particular, your unit sphere $S$ of $X$ is contained in $f(rB)$ for $r = 1/L$.

Now $S$ is a closed (because the norm is continuous) subset of a compact set, therefore it is compact.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but why does it follow that $S \subseteq f(rB)$ for $r = 1/L$?